# send action from receiver to activity?

Tags: android

I am using broadcast receiver in my app to detect incomming call and it works fine. But problem is I can not send action to activity. I mean.. I want do something in activity not in receiver. I read many tutorial but they all are performing action in receiver. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a `BroadcastReceiver` as inner class of the `Activity`. In this case you can directly call activity's methods:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            activityMethod();
        }
    };

    private final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private void activityMethod() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the `Activity` using an `Intent` and put a command code in the `Intent` extra fields. In your `Activity` you can then decide the behaviour based on the command code or resort to a default behaviour if none is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can start an activity from your receiver via the normal means:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Note though that the user is going to expect that the phone application starts up since they are receiving a phone call. It is very likely a bad idea to hijack the phone call by dumping your own activity on top of the stock dialer app.

Comment: In that case you'll want to use an BroadcastReceiver as an inner class of the activity like vmironov's answer. And I still think it is worth pointing out people are unlikely to be happy with you taking over the phone call.